# Django-mptt error. Can't find admin/mptt_change_list.html template

Tags: django, django-mptt

I\ve got a problem similar to this topic [Django-MPTT, how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350216/django-mptt-how-to)

I've added 'mptt' to INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'south',
    'mptt',
)
```

But steel I have this error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/app/category/
admin/mptt_change_list.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app/category/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
admin/mptt_change_list.html
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 131
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

It seems that template is not on it's path, but mptt is installed correctly and is on PYTHONPATH

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/mptt_change_list.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/admin/mptt_change_list.html (File does not exist)
/home/islam/DM/repo/dm/DM-165/app/templates/admin/mptt_change_list.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/debug_toolbar/templates/admin/mptt_change_list.html (File does not exist)
```

Comment: can you tell us how you installed mptt ?

Comment: @rajasimon, I've followed the documentation (http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/install.html) and  downloaded zip from here (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mptt/), then extracted data and tried this command "sudo python setup.py install". It has been installed, but didn't work. Then I've tried "pip install django-mptt --upgrade"

Comment: ok cool.. check pip freeze if mptt is there then installed app definitely load template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to delete mptt using `sudo pip uninstall django-mptt`
and install it again using pip: `sudo pip install django-mptt --upgrade`

Comment: This is surprising, but it helped me. Thanks. :D

Comment: This answers suggests installing django packages in global site (system wide). While this might temporarily work when you have just one project, it's a very bad practice. You should be using virtualenv. In my case the error was caused by not including `mptt` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. The OP had the app declared there but was probably running django as the user (without sudo) which likely caused the python to not find it or other similar. This answer is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Well as for as i know you can install Any python django package there easy ways:

1.)

You can do like via

> pip install `<package Nmae>`

for sometime `sudo pip install <packageName>` also works

2.)

Then download the `tar file` and extract from that directory you can install via

> `python setup.py insatll`

3.)

And here you did two so try this thing also

download the `mptt folder` and put it into your django project. Hope this will work

Comment: Thank you! I've tried all this. I didn't understand what was wrong, but the solution was to delete and install again using pip.